# Generate Generic JSON File with Python

Tags: python

there is something missing in my code block. I am trying to export a json file in Blender. I want the attributes part in this file to be generic. So I want to draw the names of the objects in the scene.
Here is the code block I wrote:

```
import bpy
from random import random
import json
import os

#select your collection by name (in this case the collection named "Collection")
col = bpy.data.collections["in capsule"]

objNum = len(col.objects)

#Generate random number 
randomIndex = round(random()*(objNum-1))

#use the random number to call a random object in the collection
obj = col.objects[randomIndex]

#creat a copy of the object and link it to the collection 
newObj = obj.copy()
col.objects.link(newObj)

# 1 - Export data as JSON file

# dict with all your data
dict = {
    "image": "",
    "name": "#1",
    "description": "lorem ipsum",
    "attributes":[
        {
            "trait_type": "Desk Zone",
            "value": "two legs desk",
        }
    ]
}

# encode dict as JSON 
data = json.dumps(dict, indent=1, ensure_ascii=True)

# set output path and file name (set your own)
save_path = 'C:\\Users\\pilot\\Desktop'
file_name = os.path.join(save_path, "example.json")

# write JSON file
with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(data + '\n')
```

After batFinger's comment, I tried the following and it was what I wanted. Thanks.

```
selObj = bpy.context.object
"value": selObj.name,
```

Comment: This does not seem to really be about blender, but rather python and its interactions with JSON.

Comment: No, my project is in blender and what I am trying to do is to write the objects in blender to my json file.

Comment: oh, I see it now. Sorry.

Comment: Even so, still  IMO needs some detail and clarity.  Of the data in question code example AFAICT only name _eg_  `{"name": obj.name}` is an object property.  Btw don't use `dict` as a variable name, as it is a built in type. _eg_ `data = dict()` creates an empty dictionary.  (this is why the syntax highlighter colors it red)

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER